# jQuery UI Dialogue prevent default, resume default on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, preventdefault

I'm using jQuery UI to present a dialogue box asking, "Do you really want to perform this action?" when a user clicks on a hyperlink or a form button.

If the user clicks "Confirm" then I want to perform the original default action.

Here is my code:

[html]

```
<a href="page.htm">Click me</a>
```

[jquery]

```
// Global variable keeps track of whether the user has clicked confirm

var confirmed = false;

$("a").on("click", function(e) {

    var self = $(this);

    var options = {
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        title: "Confirmation Required",
        buttons : {
            "Confirm" : function() {
                // The user has confirmed, so set global variable to true
                confirmed = true;

                // Re-trigger the click
                self.trigger("click");
            },
            "Cancel" : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't yet confirmed, display the dialogue box
    if (confirmed == false) {
        $("<div />").text("Are you sure you want to do this?").dialog(options);

        // Prevent the default action
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
    // Otherwise the user has confirmed, so don't preventDefault and return true
    else {
        confirmed = false;

        // Alert here to check we reached this point
        alert("Returning true");
        return true;
    }
});
```

When first clicking the link, the default action is prevented and the dialogue box opens.

When clicking "Confirm" in the dialogue box, the click event is triggered again, and the alert box fires saying, "Returning true".  All good so far, however the page doesn't load.  So for some reason second time around the default event is still prevented and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the fact the dialog is still open. However even if you close it, you will not be able to click the a element like this.

`trigger('click')` only triggers the function which is bond to the click event in jQuery and if you would use `$el.click()`, I think it only supports format `<a onclick="func()">Click here</a>`

How I solved this; On the dialog confirmation I update the window location with jQuery based on the `<a>` elements href.

Please see working snippet below;

```
<a href="page.htm">Click me</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  var confirmed = false;

  $("a").on("click", function(event) {

      var $self = $(this);

      if (!confirmed) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $("<div />").text("Are you sure you want to do this?").dialog({
          autoOpen: true,
          modal: true,
          title: "Confirmation Required",
          buttons : {
              "Confirm" : function() {
                  window.location.href = $self.attr('href');
              },
              "Cancel" : function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          }
        });

      }

  });

});


</script>
```

Comment: That's fine, and it's how I have it working at the moment.  However I also want to be able to attach this to a `<button>` click which would then submit the associated form once the user confirms.  This then requires some convoluted code to find out if it was a button that was clicked on or a hyperlink, and the confirm action changed accordingly.